# What set's the User.Identity.Name and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, iprincipal, iidentity

I want to know what set's the user identity name and change `isAuthenticated`to true.

Why is `User.Identity.Name` an empty string and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` `false` after `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` has returned `Success`.

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var userIdentityNameTest = User.Identity.Name; // Empty string

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                                             model.Email, model.Password, 
                                             model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    // result is "Success"

    userIdentityNameTest = User.Identity.Name;
    // userIdentityNameTest is still an empty string?
    // User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false?

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, 
                                                RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` only validates entered data and run `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` if you are not using `TwoFactorAuthentication`. `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` in this case only set authentication cookie to response.

So, `User.Identity` is available in subsequent requests to your application. To get `ApplicationUser` by `Name` you can use `ApplicationUserManager` as follows:

`UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Name)`

Comment: How can I get or set name of logged user to 'User.Identity' or 'HttpContext.User' after execution of 'SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync'?